# Angular testing, mocking service that just constructs other services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, jasmine

I understand how I would mock a function call to a service.

Although I have a case where my MainService is just a wrapper around several other services.

```
 export class MainService {
  constructor(
    public service1: Service1,
    public service2: Service2,
    public service3: Service3
){}
```

My component injects the MainService, and calls this.mainService.service2.getUsers() for example.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      providers: [
        FormBuilder,
        {
          provide: MainService,
          useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('MainService', [
            'getUsers'
          ])
        }
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent)
  })
```

I created the spyObject which mocks the MainService and added the getUsers function, I don't think this is working because the getUsers function is not directly on the MainService. How do I do this.

Comment: `jasmine.createSpyObj` should mock the public methods of `MainService`. Once you do that, you shouldn't worry about the dependencies of the other three services if mocked correctly.

Comment: @AliF50 The MainService has no public methods. Rather than injecting service2 into my component directly, MainService is being injected, this.mainService.service2.getUsers() is then called too access service2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
const mockMainService = {
  service1: {
    // mock service 1 public methods and properties here,
  },
  service2: {
    getUsers: () => {....},
    // mock service 2 public methods and properties here,
  },
  service3: {
    // mock service 3 public methods and properties here.
  }
};
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      providers: [
        FormBuilder,
        {
          provide: MainService,
          useValue: mockMainService,
        }
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent)
  })
```